# How to fix limited wifi speed broadcom bcm4311 driver? (k)ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I installed kubuntu 14.04 LTS, on an old 2007 Acer aspire celeron 5310 laptop...

It uses the broadcom BCM4311 wireless card.

Installed the broadcom drivers via:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Everything is up and running... But I am not getting full speed on my WiFi connection.

I have a 25Mb/s internet connection, and get around/close to that speed with most devices, but I only get around 13Mb/s with the laptop.

It was even worse on Ubuntu 12.04 (eOS)... Tried changing modem/router settings, and a bunch of other things without any real result.

Is this a limitation of the card, or is it possible to fix this issue??

Hope someone can help me!

Thanks!